# Run JS function in IFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, mootools, invoke

I've created an **iFrame dynamically** with **Mootools**. In my iFrame, I want to execute a function to automatically populate it.
So far, I've the following code:

```
    var mApp = this.app;
    var iframe = new Element('iframe', {
      'src' : 'frame_fittingbox.html',
      'style' : 'height:100%;width:100%;background:transparent;border:none;',
      'events' : {
        'load' : function() {
          var doc_iframe = (iframe.contentWindow) ? iframe.contentWindow : (iframe.contentDocument.document) ? iframe.contentDocument.document : iframe.contentDocument;
          doc_iframe.run(mApp, 'demo'); // FittingBox account
        },
      },
    });

    var container = this.app.page();
    iframe.inject(container);
```

In the iFrame, I've that code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="./app/components/exported_jsfile.js" />
    <script>
      function run(app, account) {
        document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="http://my.website.com/js/' +account+ '/jsfile.js">\x3C/script>');

        var customClass = new My_Custom_Class(app, document.body);
        customClass .open();
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    Loading ...
  </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work as the `run` function is never called. In the console, I got the following message: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'run'`.
What did I make wrong ?

Thanks for your precious help.

Comment: can you `console.log(doc_iframe)` in the `load` event handler?

Comment: You cannot use document.write after page load

Comment: I've logged `doc_iframe` but it gives me too many attributes to list them all.

Comment: Looks good to me. Are you sure your `run()` function is not inside another function? like `onload()`? Check here: __http://jsfiddle.net/ukKT6/__

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. I've made it working in a reversed way. I mean, the iframe is triggering parent window functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use a callback in the parent frame. So, when you need to perfom an action, use the following code:

`parent.window.parent.actionFromParent();`